# How can I send the content of file as email in Perl?

Tags: perl, file, email, text

Code for attachment

```
$msg->attach(Type        => 'document/text',

         Path        => "C:\\SDB_Automation\\sdb_dump.txt",
         Filename    => 'sdb_dump.txt',
         Disposition => 'attachment'
        );       
$msg->send;
```

I have print the data in text file and save it in my local machine. But instead of that text file I want to send only the data of that file because of the subscriber kind of thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I send the content of file as email in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325392/how-can-i-send-the-content-of-file-as-email-in-perl)

Comment: You don't want to attach the file, but to send it's contents in email body? What's the problem?

Comment: It would be far easier to help you if you told us which type of object `$msg` is. Perl has many modules for creating and sending email - you're asking us to guess which one you are using.

Comment: well data is in txt file and i want to send it in mail via perl script but i am newbie in perl thats i am looking for a help so may be someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Perl has many modules to help. try slurp for example. Hope this help.

```
use Email::MIME;
use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail);
use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP::TLS;
use Path::Class qw/file/;
use File::Type;
use MIME::Base64;
$file= file(path);
$file = scalar $file->slurp;
my $newpart = Email::MIME->create(
          attributes => {
                content_type => type,
                encoding => base64,
                disposition => $attachment->{disposition}, # maybe useful rfc2387
                charset => undef,
                name => 'attachment',
                },
                body => $file,
         );
push @parts , $newpart;
my $email = Email::MIME->create(
            header => [
                From        => " ",
                To          => "",
                Subject     => "",
                'Reply-To'  => "",
            ],
            parts => [@parts],
        );
Email::Sender::Simple->send($email)
```

Comment: well thanks for the help but i tried with outlook and it worked:P                     `code`                                                                                                  open my $fh, '<', "C:\\SDB_Automation\\sdb_dump.txt" or die "Ouch: $!\n";
 my $text1 = do {
   local $/;
   <$fh>
 };
close $fh or die "Ugh: $!\n";
print $text1,"\n";                                                                                         `code` and $message->Body("$text1");